# Excel formula IF, AND, OR - problems

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Got two formules working ok separately:

```
=IF(AND(G47<>"*ansatt",N47="AK",(OR(W47>=3000,X47>=10000,Z47>=10000,AC47>=100000,AA47>=100000,AD47>=30000))),"Yes","No")
```

and

```
=IF(AND(G47="*ansatt",N47="AK",(OR(W47>=1,X47>=1,Z47>=1,AC47>=1,AA47>=1,AD47>=1))),"Yes","No")
```

I want to combine these two into one formula. Been trying for hours, but I can't figure it out. Excel message is "there is a problem with this formula".

Here's one of my attempts, adding new "OR" up front:

```
=IF(**OR**(AND(G47<>"*ansatt",N47="AK",(OR(W47>=3000,X47>=10000,Z47>=10000,AC47>=100000,AA47>=100000,AD47>=30000)))**AND(G47="*ansatt",N47="AK",(OR(W47>=1,X47>=1,Z47>=1,AC47>=1,AA47>=1,AD47>=1))))**,"Yes","No")
```

Anyone that can help me out?

Comment: You need to tell us what the logic is here.  How should these formulas be combined?

Comment: Example: You have `W47>=3000` in the first formula and then `W47>=1` in the second formula. If you combine those conditions the second is redundant as anything >=3000 will *always* meet the criteria of >=1. Am I missing something?

Comment: The first formula looks at column G when G is unlike "*ansatt" + given values in columns W etc. In the secon formula G is changed to IS LIKE "*ansatt". But now I want to check for different values in W etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=IF(OR(AND(G47<>"*ansatt",
           N47="AK", 
           OR(W47  >=3000,
              X47  >=10000,
              Z47  >=10000,
              AC47 >=100000,
              AA47 >=100000,
              AD47 >=30000)),
       AND(G47="*ansatt",
           N47="AK",
           OR(W47  >=1,
              X47  >=1,
              Z47  >=1,
              AC47 >=1,
              AA47 >=1,
              AD47 >=1))), "Yes", "No")
```

[image: 0]